# How to copy and paste special characters out of Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, output, unicode

I'm doing a bit of string manipulation, and the output has Greek characters in it. I want to be able to copy and paste those Greek characters out of Mathematica and into another file.

For example, let's say I had output that formed a string I wanted to copy and paste into an email. Like:

```
This is true when λ=1
```

When you copy and paste this out of Mathematica however, it will change it to

```
This is true when \[Lambda]=1
```

I've tried going through all the "copy as" functions. None were helpful.